# Issue calling static methods in groovy

Tags: java, exception, groovy

We are having a code which is working fine until upgrading groovy from 2.5.7 to 2.5.18.
We started getting a strange runtime issue:

```
java.lang.VerifyError (class: utils/MyGroovyClass, method: myMethod signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal target of jump or branch
```

myMethod is static method inside my class which is calling another static method named init.
It looks like this:

```
static ubixConnectionSetting(String a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, y) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
        ...
        init()
    }
```

After trying lot of things, we ended by getting the issue fixed after changing the call to the method init by prefixing the class name (MyGroovyClass.init() instead of init()).
I'm not able to find an explanation to this (change is "stupide") nor why this started happeneing only now.
Knowing that we have in our case plenty of similar code which is also complaining about the same issue, is there any solution to understand and get this fixed properly without the "workaround" we have applied by prefixing call to a static methods within the same class by the class name.

An important information, this issue is not happening when running the code in development environment only when running it in a dockerized image.
Thanks

Comment: You sure it's running groovy 2 in the docker environment?

Comment: yes,GroovySystem.version shows we are using the correct version